# How to plot and align multiresolution images using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm looking for a way to plot multiple images with the same xlims and varying resolution which are aligned along the x-axis and stacked in y-axis.

I was able to generate what I want using subplots (shown below), but I'm curious to know if there is a better and simpler way of doing this in a single axes.

Here is the code I used to generate image below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N =10
fig,ax = plt.subplots(N,1, figsize=(16,6), sharex=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
for n in range(N):
    x = np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,(n+1)*10))
    ax[n].imshow([x, x], extent=(0,2*np.pi,0,1), aspect='auto')
    ax[n].axis('off')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting all the images in the same axes is equally possible

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N =10
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,6))
ax.axis('off')

for n in range(N):
    x = np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,(n+1)*10))
    ax.imshow([x, x], extent=(0, 2*np.pi, n, n+1), aspect='auto')
ax.autoscale()
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the solution, I was missing the autoscale() call.